# Django: is a model specific for the current day justified for performance reasons?

Tags: django, database-design, model

I want to build a website that essentially asks each day a new set of questions to its members. I plan that 90% of the load will be queries for the current day (list of the current questions, post answers to current questions). Would it be more advised (for performance reasons) to split my Question model in two: HQuestion (for historical) and CQuestion (questions for the current day) and move each day (at 0:00) questions from C to H?

Another possible advantage, in Django Rest Framework it would eliminate the need to validate if a post is sent to a current question (the only admissible post) since the post would be possible only for a CQuestion instance in the split-model scenario.

I would like to have your opinion about that, pros and cons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

for performance, I will use partition of database(etc, [mysql-guid][1]

[1]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-types.html . so it's easy to query records (combine with H & C)